# Access data from other component -React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have to access object from previous component to show in current component. I'm trying to send a state params as second parameter of navigate method.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('detail', { objPass: this.state.stObjPass });
```

while trying to access the value from current component displaying as 'Undefined'

```
   async componentWillMount() {
   console.log(this.props.state.params.objPass);
   console.log(this.props.objPass);
   console.log(this.props.state.objPass);
    }
```

All of them returning either empty or undefined.

Please let me  know how to share object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `this.props.navigation.state.params.objPass`, so you're just having an incorrect reference.

Comment: value is empty in this way

Answer (score 2):

I assume the issue is in this statement.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('detail', { objPass: this.state.stObjPass });
```

Please check whether this.state.stObjPass is correct and also check the key-value pair from the console.

```
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are passing parameters using navigation so you need to get these params from navigation like this:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.objPass
```

[Read more from here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#state-The-screen's-current-stateroute)

Comment: value is empty in this way

Comment: console.log(this.props.navigation) and check what you are getting in these props or even you are receiving the navigation or not.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we do it like:

```
onClickMore = (user) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { ...user });
};
```

and then in the component where we need it, we load from `navigation` like:

```
const { picture, name, email, phone, login, dob, location } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```

*Note: See I have used spread operator `...` which is es6 syntax to pass object, and also see how I am importing/reading in the target component using `this.props.navigation.state.params` and then destructuring it. There are other ways to write same syntax as well.*

`this.props.navigation` is available inside any component that is being rendered- directly by React Navigation *(See [documentation here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation.html))*

Now, the `navigation` is working like bridge to pass data and fetch data in a way, while doing the screen transition. (See [documentation here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html)

> For more information, please refer to this article as well (this might help):
>   https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-react-navigation-the-navigation-solution-for-react-native-ea3f4bd786a4

**Few check points:**

- Check that you have valid object in the function before passing it to `navigation`.
- You have the valid reference to `this.props.navigation`, before you pass it the data for other component/screen.
- In target component/screen, check if you have valid reference to `this.props.navigation.state`.

You can debug all these using `console.log()` function.

Also, it will be more helpful if you upload your code on Git after doing above debugging, so you get proper response. May be the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: is there  a callback method specifically to get props

Comment: Didn't get your point, please clarify (may be you are trying to catch something from the middle). The `props` are only passed as mentioned using `navigation`, and then in the target you fetch how it's been told in documentation.
If you are using a child component inside your one component, then you can pass `props` and then fetch in child component in different way. For that you can search for something like *React passing props to child component*. 
Or you can also post a separate question.