# how to pass props to all the screens in the navigator stack of react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a navigationStack A,B,C,D and I want to pass props from A->B and props from A,B-> C and props from A,B,C->D

By using this.props.navigation.navigate('B',{ props:A props }) A props are only passed to B?

Comment: combine two props and send it or you have another option to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('B',{ propsA:A props })

this.props.navigation.navigate('C',{ propsA:A props,propsB:B props })

this.props.navigation.navigate('D',{ propsA:A props,propsB:B props,propsC:C props })
```

you can able to pass multiple props to another screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to catch something in wrong way, possibly because of less domain knowledge.

The main purpose of `navigation` is to do transition from **screen-A** to **screen-B**. So this is just one transition or move. Hence, you will require to pass data from **screen-A** to **screen-B** at one time (no need to worry any other screens which are not in focus).

Then if you want to pass the data received on **screen-B** to next **screen-C** (including any newly filled user data - if any), then you will manipulate or handle on your own to pass all data to next "screen-C".

And this keeps going on. It's one kind of example is a long form. if we are taking user information in steps on different screens, then on each screen we need to pass data to next screen, and then on next screen when we take user further information, then we need to combine bod **old + new** data and pass it to next screen.

**Now, what is the basic process of passing data to next/any screen**

The `navigation` assists us to implement the screen transitions, as well as allows to pass any data to target screen. This has been explain in this very similar question quite well. I have answered there in detail:
[Access data from other component -React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563115/access-data-from-other-component-react-native)